# Bachelor's Thesis. Is ROS for me? A non hardcore programmer

Tags: ros, robot, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have a Bachelor's thesis with an end-effector on a robot, KUKA KR210. I am mostly an mechinical engineer but i start to get intrested in programming and robots. For this project i am thinking about having cameras on the end-effector as a safety feature to give the end-effector "eyes" and can act as an emergancy stop if a human is to close.
This end-effector is used in an industry production line and needs to be safe for a fitter to work along side with

Is this possible to implement? If yes, how should i do it?

Note; i am very new to this am afraid, but really like to learn and make it work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258053/bachelor%27s-thesis.-is-ros-for-me?-a-non-hardcore-programmer/) by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
I don't want to discourage you, and for a BSc it's probably ok, but a camera connected to a RPi with ROS is *never* going to get safety-rated. What you are describing ("emergency stop if a human is to close [..] needs to be safe for a fitter to work along side with") is definitely possible ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
.. but please consider that companies in this line of work (ie: safety-lasers, co-bots) spend tens of thousands of dollars developing and getting their equipment certified. A KR210 is easily capable of killing a human, so please be careful: *never* make your RPi the only system.

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
Thanks for the reply!

I see, so to get safety-rated level there's a need for a more powerful computer? Or is it the concept with cameras and the pictureprocessing that makes the reactiontimes to slow to be used as an emergency stop?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
No, my point was that making software and hardware *really* suitable for safety critical applications (which acting as an emergency stop is an example of) is hard and difficult. I'd recommend you try and talk to someone with knowledge in this field before you start.

But this all depends on ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
.. what the scope of your work is: if this is a one-off experiment for a BSc, and you're tutored by knowledgable people *and* your KR210 has additional safety measures in place, then it *could* be ok to test with your ROS application.

But don't put this in a production system -- with uninformed ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
.. users -- where there is a risk of really hurting people or damaging equipment.

Again, scope is important here, but I just wanted to point to some possible dangers.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
and finally:

> so to get safety-rated level ..

there are some experimental computer vision based systems that do something similar to this, but 1) I don't know whether they've already been certified and 2) "getting safety-rated" is probably not doable for you.

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
The scope, a robot picks up a plasticpanel and then place it under a car, then a fitter will assemble it with screws. The car will move with a constant speed and the robot with the panel will move along. So we need to make the layout and the end-effector safe for the fitter with ..

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
.. safety-rated solutions. So it may be hard to reach that level within the time for a BSc i guess?

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
Also, this BSc is for a car manufacturer and they may be using this solution

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-03-28**:
Pilz has a certified camera: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UCD77s1qvI

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
The Pilz system that @NEngelhard mentions would indeed be an option. But that would be a completely different approach, as you would basically be integrating some existing systems. I had the impression that you wanted to do 'everything' yourself.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:\

> So it may be hard to reach that level within the time for a BSc i guess?

this may sound harsh, but the fact that you are asking this gives me the impression that you're not really aware of what is involved/at stake.

Please talk to someone at the "car manufacturer" about robot safety.

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
The Pilz systems will i look into further, that seems very promising. Ofcourse would it be fun to do everything for myself. But in this BSc it's enough to do a layout of a safe working area, even with existing safety-rated systems. I really appreciate all the help and alternatives i can get! ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:\

> But in this BSc it's enough to do a layout of a safe working area, even with existing safety-rated systems

then why is your question titled: "is ros for me - a non hardcore programmer"? Integrating a pilz camera with a robot controller and some safety zones is not ROS-related at all?

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
The title is used since i want to try to use something that can be used in my BSc and found ROS that covered my problem, but my knowledge is limited in this area. Thought ROS would be an application that i could use or there would be people with more knowledge than me that could be off help ..

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
and you seem to know alot which why i ask some questions with an open mind with different approaches

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
What i mean with "So it may be hard to reach that level within the time for a BSc i guess?" if there's alot of developing and certifications needed, which you meantioned in the beginning, to reach a safety-rated level solution with cameras and ROS. In that case i don't have time to do that

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
I guess I automatically assumed that you already had made up your mind and were just inquiring as to whether this was all possible using ROS. A mistake on my part.

But safety-rated stuff is difficult, and mistakes dangerous and costly. There are better tools for that than ROS *right now* ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-28**:
.. but we are working on that and there are several initiatives underway to make ROS the go-to tool for such applications as well.

Not that that will help you right now, but I wanted to mention it.

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
I see, then ROS may not be the application for us then. I thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, is possible, I would suggest instead to place the camera over/front of the robot where you can have a fixed view pane of the Anlage, and the people that is stepping into the cell

Many tech are developed in that area, you can play with AR and markers, to define Virtual Cages for the Robot.

OpenCV, ARUCO or any other C++ based image porcessing tool/framework will help as startpoint.

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
Thanks for the reply!

Let me see if i understand you right. So you think it's a better way to have control over the collaborativ area and limit the robots movements in it?

Can it be programmed to make the robot stop as an "emergency stop" if an human gets to close to avoid an collision?

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
Or does the robot need to be equipped with, for instance, distance sensors?

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-03-28**:
KUKA KR210 is not MRK able as far as I know, so you'll need to be able to trigger the emergency stop as far as the distance between person and Roboter is too close, that it can represents a danger for the person.

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-03-28**:
you can define Virtual Rooms or Virtual Cells so the robot can move free inside that area as soon as no person is there...

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-03-28**:
Options you have:

- you can define a infra red carpet, that is triggering a emergency stop when person is in the  "Danger-Zone"
- you can use stereo cameras and make a deepth of the image so you can identify persons.(that is hard core BV)
  -you can use ultrasound, you have many options!

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.ros.org/users/29848/anton/) on 2017-03-28**:
I think this is the way we will go, using either Pilz systems or maybe SICK cameras to set up zones!